# Passing parameters to function called in a dictionary as menu in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I was asked to create a simple script to transfer data from a database to another one and to make it parametric as much as possible, including a selective menu for allowing the user to choose an operation.

As you know, Python doesn't have a **switch-case** statement and you can simulate a menu using a **if-elif...else** chain or using a **dictionary**.

I opted for the dictionary, because of a more elegant way to do it:

```
options = {
        1: ('Create temp table', create_tmp_table),
        2: ('Write data in temp table', copy_to_temp),
        3: ('Trnasfer data from temp table to final table', copy_into_main_table),
        4: ('Delete temp table', delete_tmp_table),
        5: ('Exit', exit)
    }
```

Here comes my problem. As you can see from the code, I have a function that creates a support table and takes as parameters the fields of a configuration file asked at the beginning of the script.

When I call the function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

cfg_file = raw_input('Insert configuration file: ')

try:
    params = parse_config_file(cfg_file)
    dbs = init_connection(params.src_config, params.dst_config)
except ConfigParser.Error as e:
    print e
    raise Exception('File Parsing Error')
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    print e
    raise Exception('Connection Error')
else:
    create_menu()
    choice = raw_input('\nChoose an operation: ')
    if choice in options.iterkeys():
        func= options[choice][1]
```

For example choosing operation 1, it doesn't nothing. I believe the fact that not passing any argument to the function (obviously), it does nothing.
So, how can I give the arguments to properly call the function:

```
def create_tmp_table(*varargs):
    name = raw_input('Scegli un nome per la tabella d\'appoggio')
    query = """ CREATE TABLE {0} (
                      SOME 
                      COLUMNS
                    );
                """.format(name)
    varargs[0].execute(query)
    varargs[1].commit()
```

Here is a simple output:

DB TRANSFER

1 -  Create temp table

2 -  Write data in temp table

3 -  Trnasfer data from temp table to final table

4 -  Delete temp table

5 -  Exit

Choose an operation: 1

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. So you want the create_tmp_table function called if someone chooses option 1?

Comment: I'll add a simple output to the question @Atirag

Comment: Is it possible that your `raw_input` simply returns a `str` and your keys in the dict are `int`s?

Comment: @AvihooMamka it's not just possible, that's exactly what the built in `raw_input` does and it's something OP will need to fix, either by converting the input to an int or making dictionary keys strings.

Comment: You can just use `if choice in options:` without the `iterkeys` (and in fact it will probably be faster).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, all you need to do is call the function instead of just assigning it to a variable. In other words, replace:

```
func= options[choice][1]
```

with:

```
options[choice][1]()
```

Comment: That was a copy-n-paste mistake. Anyway, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Looking closer, it looks like you do need to add some arguments to the call as well since you've got reference to `varargs[0]` and `varargs[1]`. You'll need to either make those consistent among your menu options or just hardcode them into the function itself. What are you expecting the two elements to be in this case?

Comment: I got the point of passing arguments when dispatching the function, but if I have two function that ask for a different number of args, like two args for the first one and three args for the second one?

Comment: You need some mechanism for handling that then since right now you just ask for one input. Without knowing how your options differ from what you've provided in the question, the most obvious option is to just pass a fixed set of options in that covers all cases with some parameters just not being used for some calls. For example, `create_tmp_table` might use the first two parameters, `copy_to_temp` might use parameters 1 and 3, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Method dispatching using a dictionary works like this:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    ... some code ...

def bar(arg1, arg2):
    ... some code ...

dispatcher = {'option 1': foo,
              'option 2': bar}

selected_option = 'option 1'
arg1 = 'my first arg'
arg2 = 'my second arg'

dispatcher[selected_option](arg1, arg2)
```

You have to invoke the function you take from the dictionary, that's missing in your code. Also, you have to make sure that your functions in the dict accept the parameters you pass to it when you invoke the function.

As denoted in one of the comments, make sure the key is in the dictionary. It looks like you use the user input string to select from the dict but the dict keys are ints.

Comment: Indeed, but I have other function with a different number of arguments:

dispatcher[option]foo1(arg1, arg2)



dispatcher[option]foon(arg1, arg2,..., argn)